# How to handle Run time check failure in C++?

Tags: c++, error-handling

this is the error I'm receiving:

[image]

I would like to know this:

1. how do set up `try catch` block to handle that error?
   OR
2. how do handle that error before it hapens if `try catch` is not possible?

I'm receiving this error when I call a member function trough pointer to member function with wrong signature.
That error of course won't happen if I call it with correct signature , but, I just wanna know how do I handle it if it happens.

Comment: Fix your code, don't try to 'handle' a rather fatal mishap.  Having the stack pointer imbalanced causes lots of random misery, about as bad as a corrupted heap.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I don't have to fix my code cos it has no such errors unles I do it manualy. I just wanna know if it's possible to handle that. EDIT and if it is recommended to handle such erros.

Comment: @HansPassant: I disagree about the "about as bad as a corrupted heap": It's *worse* than a corrupted heap. With a corrupted stack you cannot even safely return from your function.

Comment: OK, so the answer is: do NOT handle and fix your code. thanks I think I got your point.

Comment: @celtschk - If only that was true, code that fails immediately is much easier to troubleshoot. The typical function prologue restores the stack pointer. This tends to blow up when the optimizer is turned to eleven.

Comment: Actually you *can* disable that check with [a specific option of the compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx), but doing so is like shutting down the fire alarm because it annoys you - you will soon get burned.

Comment: well shuting down "alarm" is not what I want, but that is an option to :D

Comment: @codekiddy: the funny thing is that in the release build you will start to have "impossible" crashes due to the corrupted stack. By the way, the type system shouldn't let you call a function with the wrong signature, unless your code is filled with casts that force the conversion of function pointers. Get rid of those casts and you'll get your errors at compile time, when you'll be able to fix them easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**  You can't handle that error with `try`/`catch`.

This is because `try`/`catch` relies on the call stack and your error is that your call stack  is corrupted.

**2.**  There is no reasonable runtime method to know in advance that code is going to corrupt the stack.

These problems are typically handled by using caution when casting (function) pointers in the code itself.  The compiler will not allow an incorrect function pointer assignment unless you're forcing it with a cast.

Comment: so only handling method is using caution when casting. thanks for that explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `catch` a function call with the wrong calling convention, because it is not an exception in C++ terms.  The error is a potentially fatal one which has to do with the structure or formulation of the program, and you should not attempt to "handle" it unless you are doing some serious low-level backward compatibility stunts a la Raymond Chen.